# Bootstrap Multistep Form gets destroyed when going back

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Applications that I'm using: 
**HTML, CSS, Javascript, Bootstrap 3**

Library / Package I'm using:

`https://codepen.io/designify-me/pen/qrJWpG`

Hello and good day! I'm trying to modify a Codepen-based Bootstrap Multistep Form as mentioned from the original link above.

**My Sample Revision**

[image: Multi step]

My problem is that when I tried pressing the **Next** button and tried a use-case scenario that what if the user tried to *Go Back* using the **Previous** button, the current form is getting destroyed. I tried modifying the javascript codes given, but to no avail, everything crumbles

```
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches
var participants;

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });

    $("#rname").val($("#name").val())
    $("#remail").val($("#eemail").val())
    $("#rcontact").val($("#contact").val())
    $("#rcompany").val($("#company").val())

    participants = $("input[name='participants[]']")
        .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

    // alert(participants)
    $("#rparticipants").val(participants)
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            // current_fs.css('display', 'none');
            animating = false;
            // current_fs.hide();
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});
```

**Sample screencaps to replicate the problem mentioned above**

*After clicking the "Next" button from the 1st screencap above*

[image: After clicking the Next button]

*Then clicking the "Previous" button to edit some details*

[image: After clicking the Previous button]

**My attempts to fix the problem** 
As you can see from the code snippet above, I tried removing the **current_fs.hide()** code from the "previous" javascript function

```
complete: function(){
    //current_fs.hide();
    // current_fs.css('display', 'none');
    animating = false;
    // current_fs.hide();
},
```

The 1st step remained, but the 2nd step felt like it's still existing, but it was just hidden so the **Add** button to add more participants, isn't clickable anymore. And the elements from the 2nd step are still existing -- meaning they overlapped.

[image: Attempt 1]

May you kindly help me with this dilemma? Where as I click the **Previous** button, the website doesn't get destroyed? By the way, I'm using Laravel Blade Templating engine.

Here's my whole code: [Source Code](https://www.codepile.net/pile/VRba0MpB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first fieldset is being set `position: absolute` in the "next" animation, but is not being reset to `position: relative` after the "previous" animation.

Modify the `complete` function in the "previous" animation to add this line:

```
previous_fs.css({'position': 'relative'});
```

(Note: OP and I figured this out on a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199962/discussion-between-jueviole17-and-michael-crenshaw) from a now-deleted answer - that answer was close, but not quite right.)